# Macro for a function template: escaping issues

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I am trying to define a macro for a function template, i.e. a template where you can easily drop in relevant code but don't want to expose all of the nitty-gritty implementation details to the user. For example, I would like something like this that drops an expression into a more complex function:

```
macro make_complex_function(ex)
  quote
    function (alg,f,t,u,k)
      # Add some stuff on top
      condition1 = false
      condition2 = false
      #...
      #Put in the user's code
      $(esc(ex))
      # Put a footer
      return some,stuff,here,long,annoying,list
    end
  end
end
```

so a user could easily insert small bits of logic (with a simplified API / documentation):

```
easy_func = @make_complex_function begin
   if u > 1
      print("oh no! It happened!")
    end
 end
```

while the full power is still available for more advanced users. However, if you run that code you'll get access to undefined reference errors. I think it's because I am not escaping the expression properly, and should somehow be escaping the entire function, but am not sure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*short answer*: do NOT use `esc` or put it on the whole `quote` block.

```
julia> macro m(e)
         quote
           function f(x)
             return $(e)
           end
         end
       end
@m (macro with 1 method)

julia> f = @m x+1
#1#f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(2)
3

julia> macro m(e)
         esc(quote
           function f(x)
             return $(e)
           end
         end)
       end
@m (macro with 1 method)

julia> f = @m x+1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(2)
3
```

*long answer*:

1. something about hygiene

julia will prefix any names defined inside a macro, making them unreachable anywhere else. `esc` will cancel these prefixes so that the names in the final expression are exact what you write. So remember only use `esc` if you need to access these variables *outside* the macro, which is not the case your example.

2. use `macroexpand` to help building macroes

for example, if you put the `esc` at the wrong place like following:

```
macro m(e)
    quote
        function f(x)
            return $(esc(e))
        end
    end
end
```

you will got such a expression:

```
julia> macroexpand( :( @m x+1 ) )
quote  # REPL[9], line 3:
    function #1#f(#2#x) # REPL[9], line 4:
        return x + 1
    end
end
```

You can find that the `f` and it's argument are prefixed by a special thing(as they are not escaped), while the body is simply `x`, which is not defined anywhere.

3. better use functions rather than macroes

Generally, it's better to use higher-order functions to implement "function templates", as they are easier to read and can take advantage of modern static analysis tools - though it seems Julia did't have one yet :). Write function signatures and pass them seems annoying, but they worth it.

Comment: "Write function signatures and pass them seems annoying, but they worth it." As always, depends on what you're doing.